# What can we do to engage our users better?

Tags: discussion

I want to get feedback from all users on what you guys believe is engaging/disengaging users and what you think should be done differently.

I want to get ideas from the people that make up this website to understand better what your needs are and what you think would help our community grow.

Comment: " Lucas Kauffman **Mod** is a new contributor. Be nice" - this tickled me

Comment: @Mr.Boy well as an experienced mod yourself maybe you can provide your insights, I thought we could at least try to find some of the root causes 

Answer (score 1):

First, SE is not designed as a traditional social media platform. Thus, traditional 'user engagement' doesn't exist here. That's simply not the purpose of it. It's a more question/answer platform and less away to shout out inane unfounded opinions.

That said, it wouldn't hurt to have a little more activity here. Perhaps you might look at other hobby-specific SE sites that are more "successful" . For instance [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) does a weekly "Photo Of The Week" that is a great way to engage any user in a positive way that isn't completely restricted to question/answer. Perhaps try a similar routine i.e. 'recipe of the week' or 'brew rig picture of the week', etc etc.

Today- 'user engagement' is dependent on the user. If the user has no  immediate brewing question..there's nothing here to engage with.

Lastly- figure out what kind of user engagement you want. I was once a big contributor to other online homebrew forums (reddit specifically) and left because they're terrible. The content is lacking any depth, the community is toxic, and actual brewing information is less popular than whatever meme-ey clickbait brewing crap floats to the top. /rant

Answer (score 0):

You can find my causal analysis at the following link.  In short, forums everywhere are dying, and homebrewers are currently hanging out elsewhere.  This site simply did not make the cut for this particular hobby.  It happens.

[What happened to homebrewing?](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/486/what-happened-to-homebrewing)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking when I read the question. And I am also active on the Flemish, Dutch and British home brew forums. What this site seems to be attracting is questions which are apparently nowhere else answered.

Comment: Oh come on now, this has _got_ to be the most old-man-yelling-at-clouds answer ever. This SE site in particular has _never_ been popular and the weird gate-keeping-generation thing is a bit absurd. I'm sure homebrewers from the 80's were lamenting the use of forums ruining homebrew club participation.